# ncpu.s file was loaded in the wrong 'utf-8' android studio

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to clone [a project](https://github.com/wujianyin/Nesoid_AndroidStuido) but I get an error message in some files while run app

like that I don't know why that error raise I tried to open the file I get message with file was read in wrong UTF-8 but no thing changed too:

```
:1:1: note: while in macro instantiation
ZP_READ
^
E:/AndroidProjects/Nesoid_AndroidStuido/app/src/main/jni/neslib/ncpu.S:1734:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 ZP_READ_W
 ^
<instantiation>:2:7: error: invalid operand for instruction
 ldrb r0, [r10, r12]!
      ^
<instantiation>:1:1: note: while in macro instantiation
ZP_READ
^
E:/AndroidProjects/Nesoid_AndroidStuido/app/src/main/jni/neslib/ncpu.S:1734:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 ZP_READ_W
 ^
<instantiation>:1:1: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic, did you mean: fmov, mov, movi, movk, movn, movz, smov, umov?
movs r1, r8, lsr #1
^
E:/AndroidProjects/Nesoid_AndroidStuido/app/src/main/jni/neslib/ncpu.S:1735:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 OP_ROR
 ^
<instantiation>:2:2: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic, did you mean: orr?
 orrcs r0, r0, #0x100
 ^
E:/AndroidProjects/Nesoid_AndroidStuido/app/src/main/jni/neslib/ncpu.S:1735:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 OP_ROR
 ^
<instantiation>:3:2: error: unrecognized instruction mnemonic, did you mean: fmov, mov, movi, movk, movn, movz, smov, umov?
 movs r0, r0, lsr #1
 ^
E:/AndroidProjects/Nesoid_AndroidStuido/app/src/main/jni/neslib/ncpu.S:1735:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 OP_ROR
 ^
<instantiation>:4:6: error: invalid operand for instruction
 orr r9, r0, r0, lsl #24
     ^
E:/AndroidProjects/Nesoid_AndroidStuido/app/src/main/jni/neslib/ncpu.S:1735:2: note: while in macro instantiation
 OP_ROR
 ^
<instantiation>:5:6: error: invalid operand for instruction
 adc r8, r1, r1
     ^
```

some of file code :

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@
@@  UNDOCUMENTED
@@

op47:   @ SRE $nn
    ZERO_ADDR
    ZP_READ_W
    OP_SRE
    ZP_WRITE_W
    CYCLE_NEXT  5
```

also, you can get more details at the repo

Comment: Where is the error about UTF-8? This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the file encoding, but rather about what dialect of assembly language the file is in vs. what dialect your IDE is expecting.

Comment: it appears in the top of the IDE .. do you have any suggestions about how to solve it? or clone the repo and try to build it, please?

Comment: These sources are not compatible with the latest NDK. You need an older version of NDK (I would try r14) to build them.

Comment: how to replace mine with the older one?